# How to avoid a playbook to run when no host matches?

Tags: ansible, bamboo

**Use case:** users can provide a host name and will trigger a playbook run. In case the hostname has a typo I want to fail complete playbook run when "no hosts matched".  I want to fail it since I like to detect a failure im Bamboo (which I use for CD/CI) to run the playbook.

I have done quite extensive research. It seems that it is a wanted behavior that the playbook exists with an exit code = 0 when no host matches. [Here is one indication](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14693) I found. I agree that the general behavior should be like this.

So I need for my use case an extra check. I tried the following:

```
- name: Deploy product
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no
  any_errors_fatal: true

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Check for a valid target host 
      fail: 
        msg: "The provided host is not knwon"
      when: target_hosts not in groups.tomcat_servers
```

But since there is no host match the playbook will not run, that is ok but it also ends with exit code 0. That way I can not fail the run in my automation system (Bamboo).

Due to this I am looking for a solution to throw an exit code != 0 when no host matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a play which would set a fact if a host matched, then check that fact in a second play:

```
- name: Check hosts
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        hosts_confirmed: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

- name: Verify hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: hosts_confirmed | default(false)

- name: The real play
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts }}"
  # ...
```

Comment: Improved the answer.